# Keep getting null in XML call

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, http, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to return certain lines from an XML.

```
<geoip>
    <source>smart-ip.net</source>
    <host>68.9.63.33</host>
    <lang>en</lang>
    <countryName>United States</countryName>
    <countryCode>US</countryCode>
    <city>West Greenwich</city>
    <region>Rhode Island</region>
    <latitude>41.6298</latitude>
    <longitude>-71.6677</longitude>
    <timezone>America/New_York</timezone>
</geoip>
```

I was getting full dump before but now I'm using this code...

Which is giving me `null` for `name` when I click submit. Not sure why it's not reading the XML call.

Here is my code...

```
try {
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();

    var xml = wc.DownloadString(string.Format("http://smart-ip.net/geoip-xml/",
                                txtIP.Text));

    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(xml);

    var name = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//geoip/countryName").Value;
    txtIPresults.Text = name;
} catch (Exception myException) {
    throw new Exception("Error Occurred:", myException);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XML you are searching with `SelectSingleNode` does not contain a path that matches your parameter.  The default return for that function is null - so when your path isn't found `null` is returned.

Also, when I try to visit the webpage you specified I am getting a server error.  I recommend that you at least check to make sure that your `xml` variable has content.

**(EDIT)**

After reviewing the XML, I noticed that you are calling `Value` on the single node returned.  You don't want the value, you want the `InnerText` property - there you will find the value you are looking for.

Comment: I'm new to web services so I'm having trouble trying to get it to work. What would be the correct path to put for the xml call?

Comment: Without seeing the XML the website is returning, I can't help.  XPath queries require you to be very familiar with the exact path you are traveling.

Comment: At the moment I am behind a proxy server that may be filtering my web requests - I am getting an internal server error when I try to visit that site.  If possible, can you post the XML in the question?

Answer (score 1):

Beside using `InnerText` as Jon correctly suggest, try:

```
var name = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("countryName").InnerText;
```

I think you problem is that `doc.DocumentElement` is already the `geoip` XML element, and so you need just to get its `countryName` child.

Alternatively:

```
var name = doc.SelectSingleNode("//geoip/countryName").InnerText;
```

Comment: Hmm I tried this but I still don't get anything when I hit submit. It says null still in the debug